# C gcc expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute__' before

Tags: c, gcc

I'm very new to structs in C and I'm trying to write a program using a couple of structs and a main .c file. I'm trying to create a Create in the struct that returns a pointer to the struct for my main file to deal with.

However, every time I get the following error:
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute__' before 'createCust'
Customer createCust(...) { (with the carat at the beginning of createCust).

here are the relevant code snippets:
customer.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H
#include "order.h"

typedef struct customer *Customer;

Customer createCust(...);
void addOrder(...);

#endif
```

And customer.c:

```
#include "customer.h"
#include "order.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Customer createCust(...);

struct customer {
    int customerNum;
    char name[20];
    order orders[20];
    int index;
    int capacity;
}

Customer createCust(int id, char nam[]) {
    Customer c = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));

    // other stuff

    return c;
}
```

I am also getting another error about how order is an unknown type despite having included order.h in my file.

```
#ifndef ORDER_H
#define ORDER_H

typedef struct order *Order;

Order create(...);
#endif
```

Comment: Order is an unknown type, because it is not defined in `order.h`. You should move struct declaration (`struct order{ (...) };`) from `order.c` to `order.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of the struct's declaration, i.e.:

```
struct customer {
    int customerNum;
    char name[20];
    order orders[20];
    int index;
    int capacity;
};
```